# Magento - new custom module does not compare in Disable Module Output list

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

i’m trying to create a custom module: i followed instructions of this tutorial: http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-module-create-your-own-controller. but even copying exactly all the posted code, i can’t see the new module in backend (System->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced->Disable Modules Output). i thought could be a permission problem (i created all files with sudo permission). so i changed owner and group of all files and dirs created to www-data (sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ...), and also i gave x permission to all .xml files, but still i can’t see the new module in that list. i’ve redo once againg all the tutorial steps but nothing changed. any suggestion?

Thanx, luke

Comment: Gave you tied [official guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table#create_directories)?

Comment: tnx. i have tried to recreate the directory structure following the official wiki, but the result doesn't change...